# Is it possible to study Lie algebras without knowing too much of representation theory?

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras

There's a course on Lie Groups that I'd like to take, but it seems that for various reasons it's a good idea to take Lie algebras along with it. But after having a brief look at the contents of the courses, I found that Lie Groups focus on the interplay between algebras and calculus (well, manifolds and stuff) while Lie algebra is much more heavily centered on abstract algebra.

While I do think ideas involved in both subjects are interesting, the problem is my algebraic background is very weak: I only know of basics of rings, groups, linear algebra and *non regarding representation theory*. The course states explicitly that knowledge of representation theory is needed, and having a brief look at the lecture notes it does seem to use representation of lie algebra a lot.

I fear that

- My background (especially on representation theory) is too weak
- In terms of exam performance, I'm worried whether this weakness might affect my overall performance.

So I'd like to know:

- Is it possible to have decent understanding in the subject without much knowledge of representation theory?

PS: The reason I want to study Lie theory is mainly for my interest in differential geometry

Comment: This is going to depend heavily on the specific courses.  A Lie groups course could just use a few straightforward aspects of Lie algebras, or it could use a lot of the algebraic theory.

Comment: I would ask the professor. I think that's the only real answer here. There are so many ways of approaching this subject. It certainly doesn't have to be this way, in that you can witness the number of books on Lie groups that don't suppose anything beyond some basic differential geometry and abstract algebra; sometimes even less than that.

Comment: Strangely, although some connections to Lie algebra is mentioned in the course it does not assume knowledge of Lie algebras or anything and as far as I can see after reading notes on this subject it's quite self contained.

Comment: You need not be afraid of representation theory. The basics are no more difficult than the basics of Lie algebras. Your "overall performance" is mainly influenced by your will to learn some basics from other fields which you will need for differential geometry.